# 200% zoom in Ubuntu 18.04.2 setting value got reset constantly in VirtualBox

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, display-resolution, mac

I've got macOS Mojave 10.14.5 in which I run in VirtualBox Ubuntu 18.04.2. 
In Ubuntu everything is quite small as mac has high resolution. I found that setting display to 200% is ideal for me, but once I set the value if I change the window size of my VirtualBox VM the 200% settings got lost and I have again 100%. So I have to go again into settings and specify 200%.

How I can set it once and for all?

Comment: You can't because that's how it works: Different resolutions may require different scaling. It's only logical that by changing the resolution - which happens in a VM if you go full screen - it reverts to the default scaling.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia the key point is the word "May" and if we look deeper that May would be in 3-5% of the cases in most of the cases I'd like it to be the way I configured. I think it would be better if it require a change then I go and do a change manually, instead of each time I forced to do that. Ubuntu screen was perfectly working in VirtualBox on any resolutions. I believe keeping that value as user set is better that doing just a reset.